# How to build a talend job as a web service with parameters and multiple strings as output

Tags: web-services, request, response, talend

I have a talend job designed to do an ETL task. I am using the talend open studio for data integration. I have gone through the beginners, and components manuals(of TOS 5.6), but cannot find a way to design a job that could be exported as a web service such that it could be called with parameters in the request, and then getting a collection of strings as the response. I found out that in the version 5.1  there were components like tRestRequest, and tRESTResponse that were used to achieve what I want, but for versions above 5.1 I have found nothing helpful.

Comment: what about the twebserviceinput or twebservice components?

Comment: @elvainch I don't want to call a webservice. I want to build my job such that I can deploy it as a webservice on a server. Now my problem is I don't know how to parse input parameters when calling the webservice from another client and also how to return the response with a  collection of say  Strings. For the moment I am using context parameters and I am calling the job manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web service and REST components are now the part of the Talend ESB. In Talend DI only the consumer components are remained. You can download ESB, and build standalone job or set up an ESB server and deploy your jobs there.
The ESB is available here: http://www.talend.com/download/talend-open-studio?qt-product_tos_download=2#qt-product_tos_download

Comment: Thanks very much @Ernest.